How does ATSAM3X8E's SAM-BA bootloader work?
I'm trying to understand the boot process section in the datasheet for ATSAM3X8E. According to the datasheet, this chip comes with SAM-BA bootloader at address 0x00000000:

If the bootloader is going to loop indefinitely for a connection to SAM-BA monitor, does it not boot in the absence of SAM-BA monitor?
If I flash my program to address 0x00080000 (first address after the boot section in the flash) using some other means, can the bootloader jump to 0x00080000 somehow? In the datasheet, it also says that the remaining space after the bootloader can also be used by the program. So, if the size of the bootloader is x, then can I upload the program to address 0x00000000+x? If I could, then how would the chip know, after executing the bootloader, that it should go to 0x00000000+x, not 0x00080000?
I'm very confused by this section of the datasheet. Appreciate some help with understanding this.

The SAM3X8E can be configured to boot to SAM-BA monitor (the default), or to Flash 0 or 1.  This is done via the GPNVM bits and is described in section 7.2.4 of the datasheet.  Setting GPNVM1 to 1 allows booting to Flash 0 or Flash 1.  When GPNVM1 is 1, GPNVM2 selects Flash 0 (GPNVM2 clear) or Flash 1 (GPNVM2 set).
